# how to turn a kindle-berry into a real powerful computer?

Tags: android-things

I'm new to the Raspberry Pi. I'm currently studying programming and think I need a kindle-berry to sit outside and study. I would like a cheap e-ink screen in the end that can run Android Studio/IntelliJ.

My laptop can easily run Android Studio and other IDE's but the kindle-berry won't run the virtual device. I have read this is due to its low RAM and processor power. Is that correct?

I guess instead of running a virtual device I could test the apps I make directly onto a real phone. Can the Pi be connected to my computer so I can use the RAM in the laptop (8 GB), instead of the Pi? Or is there a different way of doing this?

Comment: Why not just use the laptop to sit outside and study?

Comment: I'm guessing because they are often horrible with glare.   This kinda maybe boils down to a "have my cake and eat it too" problem which a Raspberry Pi won't solve, it will only change the focus of the problem.

Comment: This is highly unlikely to save money, or provide satisfactory performance. Precisely for the reasons you point out its low memory and relatively slow processor.

Answer (score 3):

> the kindle-berry won't run the virtual device. I have read this is due to its low RAM and processor power. Is that correct?

That would be a major stumbling block. I would not want to bother trying Android development on a machine with only 1 GB of RAM, although that doesn't mean it is completely impossible, at least via the use of [swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#LINUX).

The problem with this is if you are using a lot of it (e.g., more swap than RAM), the fastest *potential* for this on the Pi is going to be ~30 MB/s via USB (that potential will not even be halfway met most of the time).  I'm not sure of the actual memory bus speed used on the Pi; the RAM itself is I think 900 Mhz, although there's a clock used set to less than half that, but it still probably isn't a significant bottleneck (i.e., the CPU does not have to spend much of its time waiting on RAM).

In any case, 0.25 - 1 GHz transfers on a 32-bit bus still equate to speeds at least several orders of magnitude faster than anything that will be possible with swap.  So think about many things taking *hundreds of times longer* to complete.

A further problem is that the x86(-64) processors used on most normal computers have evolved a lot of support for [virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization#Hardware_virtualization). I believe this really only applies to virtual instances of the same architecture, but in general, consider x86 more performance oriented and feature rich than [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) (the Pi, and most mobile devices).  What makes things like the Android emulator feasible are muscular x86-64 CPUs and a massive amount of fast RAM.  The ARM family fills a different niche with different priorities (lower power consumption and production costs).  Emulation is still possible, but as an example, a number of years ago someone got a version of MS Windows running in an emulator on an Rpi model B.  It took *20 minutes to boot*.

Of course, most Android devices are ARMv7 or 8, so this is less of a stretch than emulating a PC for Windows.  However, I still think it will be a waste of time, which is why as far as I am aware no one has bothered compiling the Android emulator for the Pi.

You *might* still be able to run IntelliJ or Eclipse usably, and `adb` is available for Raspbian, so you might even be able to compile code and test it on an attached device.  I would not recommend this to people though.  I think in the end it will not be very worthwhile (though people who did a lot of programming in the 70's and 80's would probably chuckle at that).

There are, of course, other things besides Android to study that are much more suited to a Pi.

> Can the Pi be connected to my computer so I can use the RAM in the laptop (8 GB), instead of the Pi?

No.  At least, not in a way that isn't constrained by the same transfer speed bottleneck as the swap problem already described, meaning you might as well just use swap.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will try to jail break a kindle instead and use it directly with my main computer. thanks for the fast answer :)